# Most common partial string match in list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large-ish list of strings (no more than 2k) and I want to find the most common partial string match within the list. For example I'm trying to satisfy the following test case in an efficient manner.

```
data = [
    'abcdef',
    'abcxyz',
    'xyz',
    'def',
]
result = magic_function(data)
assert result == 'abc'
```

I've tried this with inspiration from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794481/python-finding-most-common-pattern-in-list-of-strings), but the fact that some elements in the list are completely different throws it off.

```
def magic_function(data):
    return ''.join(c[0] for c in takewhile(lambda x: all(x[0] == y for y in x), zip(*data)))
```

Comment: what happens if there is also a `'ape'` in your `data` - would then `'a'` be your magic thing? And if not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to tweak this and perfomance test it.

I essentially feed all partial substrings up to the lenght of each word in `data` [into a `Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and create a ranking based on `len(substring)*occurence` - penalizing occurences of only 1 by multiplying wiht 0.1:

```
data = [
    'abcdef',
    'abcxyz',
    'xyz',
    'def',
]    

def magic(d):
    """Applies magic(tm) to the list of strings given as 'd'.
    Returns a list of ratings which might be the coolest substring."""
    from collections import Counter
    myCountings = Counter()

    def allParts(word):
        """Generator that yields all possible word-parts."""
        for i in range(1,len(word)):
            yield word[:i]

    for part in d:
        # count them all
        myCountings.update(allParts(part))

    # get all as tuples and sort based on heuristic length*occurences
    return sorted(myCountings.most_common(), 
                  key=lambda x:len(x[0])*(x[1] if x[1] > 1 else 0.1), reverse=True)

m = magic(data)    
print( m ) # use  m[0][0] f.e.
```

Output:

```
 [('abc', 2), ('ab', 2), ('a', 2), ('abcde', 1), ('abcxy', 1), 
  ('abcd', 1), ('abcx', 1), ('xy', 1), ('de', 1), ('x', 1), ('d', 1)]
```

You would have to tweak the sorting criteria a bit and only use the first in the resulting list - but you can use that as starter.

Tweaking could be done by multiplying the length by a faktor if you prefer longer ones over multiple short ones - that depends on your data...

Comment: Cool, this seems to work well!
I'm going do so some profiling to see if it can be improved performance-wise, but I think this will work for now.  Thanks!